# Are people expected to live over 100 now?

Tags: life-expectancy

I noticed when reading PDS's of life insurance companies, some of them have an age cap of 99. Of course, they have to be profitable, and if everyone dies at an average of 90 years of age, then they'd soon be bankrupt. There must be a reason why they set their maximum age to 99.

Given this, and current health trends, are current-gen people expected to live over 100 now?

Answer (score 3):

Predicting life expectancy of people currently alive, can, of course, only be speculation, but one based on statistics. If there is a nuclear war next year, the predicted life expectancy will not be accurate.

For the United States, [the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/hus/hus14.pdf#016) estimated a life expectancy of about 80 for children born in 2013 (table 16). 71 is the estimated expected life span at birth by [the WHO](http://www.who.int/gho/mortality_burden_disease/life_tables/situation_trends/en/) for children born in 2012. This includes all countries.

However, these are medium values (often medians, meaning half of all people will reach a higher age), and people getting over 100 years is certainly not unheard of, even today. In 2012, there were over 300,000 people alive [who are over 100](http://www.unfpa.org/sites/default/files/resource-pdf/UNFPA-Report-Chapter1.pdf). The US [had over 7,000 of them alive in 2011](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html) .

As for predictions for over-100s: For the UK, [one third of babies born in 2013 are expected to live to 100](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/lifetables/historic-and-projected-data-from-the-period-and-cohort-life-tables/2012-based/sty-babies-living-to-100.html).